# Flask-SQLAlchemy raises TypeError: Query.paginate() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I call Flask-SQLAlchemy's `query.paginate` method with arguments. Recently this stopped working and instead raised a `TypeError`. How do I pass `page` and other arguments to `query.paginate`?

```py
Ticker.query.paginate(page, app.config["TICKERS_PER_PAGE"], False)
```

```
TypeError: Query.paginate() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0, all arguments to `paginate` are keyword-only.

```py
Ticker.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=app.config["TICKERS_PER_PAGE"], error_out=False)
```